# Middle click tab bar to open new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to developing chrome extensions and was curious if there was a way to track for a middle click in the tab bar to open a new tab (much like in firefox). I know there is `window.open()`  to open a link in a new tab and `onauxclick=`  to track for a middle click. As small as it is, it's one of the main benefits to using Firefox. If there's something out there that already achieves this I would be keen to hear about it. I'm guessing this is a lot more complicated than I thought it might be, but keen to hear any thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to detect this in browser or via chrome extensions API. You can write a separate utility that uses native OS methods to intercept mouse clicks and communicate with an extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) or simply send WM_COMMAND message with wParam=APPCOMMAND_NEW.

Comment: Hmmm ok, I'll look into it a bit. Totally new to me though.

Comment: FWIW, AutoHotkey is often used for such tasks in Windows.